# What technologies do I need to know to set up a newsletter?

Tags: mailchimp, newsletter

I'm not going to start a big company, it's just a weekend project. I will do it alone. I know PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, MySQL. I can learn a new programming language or technology depending on the situation. Don't tell me "you can't do what you say", "you can't do without a team". Tell me everything you know. Give a solution-oriented answer. Please respond according to what I have said. I'm just asking how to do it. Please do not give unnecessary answers.

Solutions I can think of:

- Using the Mailchimp APIs

Can people make their own newsletters with the Mailchimple API? For example: Like Tinyletter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using exactly what you said in your question.

Use PHP to communicate with the Mailchimp API, MySQL to store any information you need in a database (if its needed) and HTML, CSS and JS to render whatever you need on the client side.

That being said, its not evident building mailers from scratch to accommodate every or most email applications (software like **outlook** or **thunderbird**, web driven like **gmail**, etc.). Build your templates within mailchimp and use the api to create campaigns and assign recipients/lists to that campaign.

[Mailchimp api documentation can be found here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/fundamentals/)

Comment: I forgot to add something to my question. Can people make their own newsletters with the Mailchimple API? For example: Like Tinyletter. (I'm updating my question now.:)

Comment: @UğurKILCI Do you mean to create the actual content of the email through the mailchimp api?

Comment: I want to create a website where people like Tinyletter can set up newsletters.

Comment: So in essence your trying to be a reseller using the mailchimp api? Basically you want to use the mailchimp API to provide people with the ability to create their own lists and templates and send out newsletter campaigns that way?

Comment: Yes. Whichever is most appropriate. Using API or making from scratch.

Comment: Your going to need to answer a lot more questions to yourself before you can make that decision, but ultimately it is your decision. Now you should probably read on the Mailchimp API to figure out if everything you want can be done before considering that option. Starting something from scratch is also doable, but a lot harder and time consuming, and you will need to learn everything there is to learn about how emails, subscribers and newsletters work and the rules and regulations behind them.